# AngularJS not working on ajax loaded content in MVC view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view page, which is a common page where other pages are jQuery-ajax loaded. AngularJS controller and directives are not working on that loaded content. AngularJS is working on the common page. I am not getting any error on the console, only one warning  - 'Tried to load angular more than once'. There was indeed a similar question i saw , but there the answer given was badly formed html. However, don't think that's the case here.

I had only just started writing angular in this application. I moved the angular script to the common page and then to even the layout page ( in MVC , tihs is the page which acts like a Master view). I tried putting the smallest possible angularjs code possible just to check if i was wrong somewhere. But its still not working.

This is the html which get dynamically loaded.

```
<div class="form-horizontal" ng-app="address">
   <div ng-controller="rulesController">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar" ng-init="myVar = true">
       <div ng-if="myVar">
           <h1>Welcome</h1>
           <p>Welcome to my home.</p>
           <hr>
       </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is the angular script. Scope only has one variable and this is the only controller in the module -

```
 angular.module('address', []).controller('rulesController', ['$scope',function ($scope) {                   
     $scope.myVar = '';
 }]);
```

Comment: @georgeawg - I tried angular.bootstrap and it still doesnt work. I used  -  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document, ["address"]); where 'address' is my angular module. Removed the ng-app directive too as mentioned in various links including the one given by you.

Comment: @georgeawg - So what was happening was that I had dynamic Ajax content getting loaded during one of the page navigations, so even manual bootstrap was before the content getting loaded. So I attached manual bootstrap as callback to onsuccess of ajax loaded content. AngularJS is working now on that page , but the problem is I still see the warning  - 'Tried to load angular more than once' and also another error  - 'bootstrap already done'.

Comment: Read [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: `ng:btstrpd`
App Already Bootstrapped with this Element](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd)

Comment: @georgeawg - I have removed ng-app directive, so its not possible for bootstrap to happen again through that.

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, page navigations are done with either the `ng-view` directive or the `ng-include` directive. Both those directives automatically remove DOM when switching templates. There are also third party libraries such as [UI-Bootstrap Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!tabs). Using [jQuery load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is not recommended as it is not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.